# Font trouble for media temple hosting

Tags: css, fonts, hosting

Has anyone used media temple hosting and used a custom font webkit? If so, whats the appropriate path for the css?

I have been using

```
/home/22381/users/.home/domains/ferventchirps.com/html/fonts/textanarrow-regular-webfont.ttf
```

but it is not available.

Essentially I have everything set up on the media temple side of things. I've uploaded the webfont correctly and applied the css but the path seems to be wrong. Right now it's set up as:

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: 'texta_narrowregular';
    src: url('/home/22381/users/.home/domains/ferventchirps.com/html/fonts/textanarrow-re‌​gular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/home/22381/users/.home/domains/ferventchirps.com/html/fonts/textanarrow-re‌​gular-webfont.eot?#iefix')
            format('embedded-opentype')
         url('/home/22381/users/.home/domains/ferventchirps.com/html/fonts/textanarrow-re‌​gular-webfont.woff2')
            format('woff2'),
         url('/home/22381/users/.home/domains/ferventchirps.com/html/fonts/textanarrow-re‌​gular-webfont.woff')
            format('woff'),
         url('/home/22381/users/.home/domains/ferventchirps.com/html/fonts/textanarrow-re‌​gular-webfont.ttf')
            format('truetype'),
         url('/home/22381/users/.home/domains/ferventchirps.com/html/fonts/textanarrow-re‌​gular-webfont.svg#texta_narrowregular')
            format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What have you tried?

Comment: essentially i have everything set up on the media temple side of things. ive uploaded the webfont correctly and applied the css but the path seems to be wrong. right now its set up as: "@font-face {
    font-family: 'texta_narrowregular';
    src: url('/home/22381/users/.home/domains/ferventchirps.com/html/fonts/textanarrow-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/home/22381/users/.home/domains/ferventchirps.com/html/fonts/textanarrow-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),

Comment: url('/home/22381/users/.home/domains/ferventchirps.com/html/fonts/textanarrow-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('/home/22381/users/.home/domains/ferventchirps.com/html/fonts/textanarrow-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/home/22381/users/.home/domains/ferventchirps.com/html/fonts/textanarrow-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/home/22381/users/.home/domains/ferventchirps.com/html/fonts/textanarrow-regular-webfont.svg#texta_narrowregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}"

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the code and format it correctly.  No one can read it when so much of it is in the comments.

Comment: I copied the comments into the question and put in a lot of code formatting to improve readability.